# Creating virtualenv using altinstall

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have just done a fresh install of Linux Mint 17.3. It comes with both python 2.7 and 3.4. I usually work with multiple versions of python so I just do an altinstall and then for each project I create a virtualenv using the desired version of python. However im running into issues with the newly installed OS. First a few things i've already done following the install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

I did an altinstall of python3.3.5:

```
downloaded the source tarball
./configure --with-zlib
sudo make
sudo make altinstall
```

I then tried creating a virtualenv in a new folder to test:

```
virtualenv -p python3.3 venv
```

This gave an error:

```
no module named zlib
```

I've had this issue in the past, so I did:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Now when I create the virtualenv the zlib error is gone, however im getting a new error and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.3
Using base prefix '/usr/local'
New python executable in venv/bin/python3.3
Also creating executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
Complete output from command /home/vega/Documents...8/venv/bin/python3.3 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 35, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 66, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2363, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1004, in create_environment
install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 969, in install_wheel
'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 910, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/vega/Documents...8/venv/bin/python3.3 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

I read somewhere that this might have something to do with openssl so I did:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

No luck, still having the same issue.

Comment: You can try doing the install without using the `sudo` for installing `python-dev` and `zlib`, I had similar issues.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a try. It gave an error saying unable to lock file. So I logged in as root and then did a --reinstall on all the above items. Still no luck, same issue.

Comment: @TonyRoczz ok your suggestion has worked, but it required that after installing all the packages not using sudo,...you then need to reinstall the python altinstall ie: re-do the whole configure/make etc. Now its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I let someone else do the work, so I don't have to worry about building alterante versions myself from source.

I've had really good luck using Felix Krull's "deadsnakes" PPA for installing alternate Pythons on Ubuntu.  Would this work for Mint 17? (based on Ubuntu Trusty)

'deadsnakes PPA' packages versions of Python: 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 ... all available to install from `apt`.  Once installed, You can manage versions and dependencies with virtualenv and pip.

Installing Python 3.5 from deadsnakes PPA:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3.5 python3.5-dev
```

The PPA maintainer has maintained these for quite a long time and updates with each Ubuntu release.

https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes

Comment: Thanks, everything seems to be working for now thanks to the previous suggestion,...but ill keep this in mind for when I next need a different version of python.